# Equivalence classes in completness proof of predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am reading Henkin style proof of completeness of predicate logic. In the proof, the language includes an equality symbol ($\equiv$). I remember reading [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/the-completeness-and-compactness-theorems-of-first-order-logic/) that equality symbol is optional. The way this is handled in the proof is by redefining the symbol set using the equivalence class defined by the equality relation. I have two questions 1. Why is this symbol optional? 2. If it is removed, how would it affect the proof?

Comment: From the article you cite: "As we shall see shortly, one can also essentially eliminate the privileged role of the equals sign $=$ by treating it as just another binary relation, which happens to have some standard axioms attached to it."

Comment: 1. Tao says equality is optional because the proof goes through with or without it. 2. the completeness proof doesn't depend on any special properties of equality.